# Why does keyup doesn't return false while keydown do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyup

Why does `return false` doesn't work with `keyup` event while in `keydown` event it actually worked.

Please see this snippet for **KeyDown Event**:

```js
var max = 10;
$('#txt').keydown(function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode;
      
  var printable = 
      (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58)   || // number keys
      keycode == 32 || keycode == 13   || // spacebar & return key(s) (if you want to allow carriage returns)
      (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91)   || // letter keys
      (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112)  || // numpad keys
      (keycode > 185 && keycode < 193) || // ;=,-./` (in order)
      (keycode > 218 && keycode < 223);   // [\]' (in order)
 
  if (printable) {
    return $(this).val().length < max;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" id = "txt">
```

And this snippet for **KeyUp Event**:

```js
var max = 10;
$('#txt').keyup(function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode;
      
  var printable = 
      (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58)   || // number keys
      keycode == 32 || keycode == 13   || // spacebar & return key(s) (if you want to allow carriage returns)
      (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91)   || // letter keys
      (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112)  || // numpad keys
      (keycode > 185 && keycode < 193) || // ;=,-./` (in order)
      (keycode > 218 && keycode < 223);   // [\]' (in order)
 
  if (printable) {
    return $(this).val().length < max;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" id = "txt">
```

Can somebody explain to me why? Thanks.